# document.body.innerText doesn't select all text from page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select all text from a given page

```
var somePageText = document.body.innerText;
```

and have found a situation where it won't select text within a table that is rendered dynamically using jsGrid.

.innerHTML doesn't work, .textContent doesn't work.

window.find and hitting ctrl-f sees this text, as I'm able to search through it.

Is there a more complete method of select ALL text from a page without picking up excessive markup?

Comment: `innerText` _should_ pick up all the text. Are you sure you're using it properly? If you have a snippet of HTML you can add to your question where `innerText` doesn't return the expected result, that'll help us figure it out.

Comment: Spec for `innerText` for your reference. Maybe the devil's in these details: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute

Answer (score 0):

is that editor text you want to select all? if yes, try this.

```
document.execCommand("selectAll", false, null);
```

it work if it on the editor text. not tested on entire html. null is an object. maybe u can put document.getElementsTagByName("body");
and false is used if you use a button. so when click it will be true. if u want start selectAll without button, use true instead of false.and put that function on the body onload, or anywhere u want to select all.

hope it work.

Comment: I believe @NoCarrier means he wants to _read_ all text, not select the text in a `contentEditable`. Gotta love those ambiguous terms :D

Comment: oopsss sorry :D , i think he develop some text editor. well then, its not work. try another solution. :D